# Hibernate-OGM (neo4j) deserted

Tags: hibernate-ogm

Lastly, I've interested in `hibernate ogm`.

I've realized last release is from 2018!!!

Is this project deserted?

I've currently involved into a neo4j project, and would like to configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this project deserted?

At the moment, yes. There are no future plans for this project.

https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/is-ogm-a-dead-framework/5716